# Want to enclose data with CDATA at runtime in XML

Tags: java, xml

I am getting xml file. I want enclose data within CDATA wherever i find & in my xml file. how should i do it? 
any help would be appreciated.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't & forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: thanks for editing david99world.. I am about to edit it just now :)

Comment: How your generating the xml ? while adding the textnodes u can check & occurrence and then surround with CDATA

Comment: I am getting generated xml from client side. I just want to pass it to some webservice. but while parsing it's not validating correctly because it's treating & as special char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
        CDATASection cdata = doc.createCDATASection("mycdata");
        cdata.appendData("contents");
        element.appendChild(cdata);
```